# find number of polygons a line intersects

Tags: sql, sql-server, geometry, geospatial, geography

I am working with SQL Server and spatial types. Have found the very interesting. I have reached a situation and I am not sure how I might work it out. Let me outline

I have 2 points (coordinates) eg. 3,9 and 50, 20 - this is a straight line, joining such.

I have multiple polygons (50 +).

I want to be able to calculate how many polygons that the above line passes through. What I mean by pass through, when I join the 2 coordinates, how many polygons the line intersects? I want to work this out with a SQL query.

Please let me know if not clear - it is difficult to explain!

Comment: I cannot believe that 12k+ user asked such question :(

Comment: No attempt? No table structure? Nothing???  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Ben was very helpful with answering my question - no issue with detail for him.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your coordinates, I'm assuming geometry (as opposed to geography), but the approach should hold regardless. If you have a table `dbo.Shapes` that has a `Shape` column of type geometry and each row contains one polygon, this should do:

```
declare @line geometry = geometry::STLineFromText('LINESTRING(3 9, 50 20)', 0);

select count(*)
from dbo.Shapes as s
where s.shape.STIntersects(@line) = 1;
```

If you want to know *which* polygons intersect, just change the `count(*)` to something more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks Ben for your helpful and constructive answer - did exactly what I needed.